# Help with convergence of $\sum_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if the following series is convergent or not?
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

I tried to prove it by Leibnitz's test ,  but I'm not sure if $\sin(1/n)$ is monotonic.

Comment: Look at the graph of $\sin$.

Comment: I looked and i saw that from some point the graph is monotonic but not from the beginning ..

Comment: The (finite) beginning doesn't matter.

Comment: $\sin(1/n)$ *is* monotonic for large $n$, that's enough.

Comment: Ok i got it!! thank you!

Comment: Actually it's monotonic from the very beginning since $\dfrac1n\in\Bigl[0,\dfrac\pi2\Bigr]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once $n>0$, increasing $n$ means decreasing $\frac 1n$ toward zero, and since $\sin x$ is an increasing function for $-\frac{\pi}2\le x\le \frac{\pi}2$, that means that $\sin\frac 1n$ is decreasing.

We also have that $\frac 1n\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$, so the criteria for alternating series with decreasing absolute value tending to zero applies, and the series thus converges.